# Which is more accurate method for finding distance between two locations in google maps in android? distanceTo or Distance?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to make an android app to find distance between origin and destination for Driving. So I will need to find the accurate distance for the path I drive. To achieve this I am getting my location every 5 secs and calculating the distance using `distanceTo()` and `distanceBetween()` methods of [`Location`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class of google maps. Please help me in deciding which method to use.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread however replying for help to anyone in future.

In Android SDK, distanceTo and distanceBetween return Inverse/Vincenty formula based distances see [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938672/android-best-method-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations) which is bit more accurate compared to haversine distance formula.

Apart from these, distance returned by above doesn't return travel-able distance [i.e. not accurate enough for navigation]. Hence use google maps based Distance Matrix API [[webservice/restful and JS apis]](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) to get travel-able accurate distance. However note that free version of this api has limitations and they have premium version for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those methods will show you the distance as the bird flies, not by road. To get the distance by road, you need to ask Google, this way:

```
public String getDistance(final double lat1, final double lon1, final double lat2, final double lon2){
String parsedDistance;
String response;
    Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + lat1 + "," + lon1 + "&destination=" + lat2 + "," + lon2 + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving");
                final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
                JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
                parsedDistance=distance.getString("text");

            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
thread.start();
try {
    thread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return parsedDistance;
}
```

parsedDistance variable will give you the distance, in kilometers, between two given points.

EDIT

Alternatively, you can give the control to the Google Maps App, if it is installed, this way:

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=" + origin.getLatitude() + "," + origin.getLongitude() + "&daddr=" + destination.getLatitude() + "," + destination.getLongitude();
                Uri urimap = Uri.parse(uri);
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, urimap);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
```

This way, the phone will open the Google Maps app and show the route between the two set points.

Comment: It's important to note that this method would give the distance in a route calculated by Google. It may not be what OP is after since his/her route might be different than Google's

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But, Google will send you back the shortest route. Looks like ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which method is more accurate , but according to my prior experience **distanceBetween()** works well . I have used this method for the same point of view as you have . I would suggest you to use this one .

Comment: As I say in my answer, the two methods you are asking will not give you distance by road. If straight line distance is what you are after, use one of those methods. If you need distance by road, it will give you wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

- The two methods [distanceBetween()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) and [distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) have
  different purpose.
- As [distanceBetween()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) docs says it provides us with the distance in meters and the bearing of shortest distance between them. It has an plus point of providing us with a bearing which the [distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) does not give.
- *According to [distanceBetween()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) docs-*

  > The computed distance is stored in results[0]. If results has length 2
  >   or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results [ 1 ]. If results
  >   has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results [ 2 ].

  So you will get the distance and bearing in this function.
- But in the other hand when we need a handy tool to get only the distance between two location with doing much of work. we will use [distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) .
- This function straightly return us the distance between two location in meters as a float value.

> Which is more accurate method for finding distance between two
>   locations in google maps in android? distanceTo or Distance?

*The answer to your question is the result will be same in both the functions. its has different propose but never give different result.*

So you have to decide which functionality do you need. and use the appropriate function. Hope this answer helps you.